# I want to make mongodb aggregate lookup to join programs array module_id with module_attempts key from below users collection

Tags: mongodb

this is current collection

```
// collection: users
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63ab0d0ed5e1b9566e0a2632"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2022-12-27T20:49:42.350+05:30"),
    "programs" : [
        {
            "program_id" : "5c1a01c6079288177e793c82",
            "modules" : [
                {
                    "module_id" : "5d5e9d990792882b250ecbf2",
                    "module_instance_id" : "63ab0dedd5e1b9566e0a2638"
                },
                {
                    "module_id" : "5d5671e9079288617b1eaf72",
                    "module_instance_id" : "63abf24b8c5554a06f0dcf52"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "program_id" : "5c401f7307928872bf7ed303",
            "modules" : [
                {
                    "module_id" : "5d4bffd70792883e8b16b066",
                    "module_instance_id" : "63ac4ccd9273aa285f011772"
                },
                {
                    "module_id" : "5d5684ff0792886b371d9dc2",
                    "module_instance_id" : "63ad866b32b504b0340449d2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "module_attempts" : {
        "5d5e9d990792882b250ecbf2" : { //module_id
            "63ab0dedd5e1b9566e0a2638" : { //module_instance_id
                "start_date" : "2022-12-27 15:33:53",
                "module_instance_id" : "63ab0dedd5e1b9566e0a2638"
            }
        },
        "5d5671e9079288617b1eaf72" : {
            "63abf24b8c5554a06f0dcf52" : {
                "start_date" : "2023-01-02 11:11:17",
                "module_instance_id" : "63abf24b8c5554a06f0dcf52"
            }
        },
        "5d5684ff0792886b371d9dc2" : {
            "63ad866b32b504b0340449d2" : {
                "start_date" : "2023-01-02 13:57:27",
                "module_instance_id" : "63ad866b32b504b0340449d2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`module_attempts` array two keys are `module_id` and `module_instance_id`.  Im trying to  do below tasks and active results array.

1.Combine program users.programs.modules in to one array which contain all modules for a user
2.Iterate over the new module array and combine with module_attempts array by using module "module_instance_id"

**Results array like that I need to get:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63ab0d0ed5e1b9566e0a2632"),
    "module_instance_id" : "63ab0dedd5e1b9566e0a2638",
    "module_id" : "5d5e9d990792882b250ecbf2",
    "start_date" : "2022-12-27 15:33:53", // this is start_date that inside the start_date
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63ab0d0ed5e1b9566e0a2632"),
    "module_instance_id" : "63abf24b8c5554a06f0dcf52",
    "module_id" : "5d5671e9079288617b1eaf72",
    "start_date" : "2023-01-02 11:11:17",
}
{
....
}
```

I've tried with below function

```
db.users.aggregate([
     { "$match": { "_id": ObjectId("63ab0d0ed5e1b9566e0a2632") }},
  {
    $unwind: "$programs"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$programs.modules"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "programs.modules.module_id",
      foreignField: "module_attempts",
      as: "module_attempts"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$module_attempts"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "programs.modules.module_attempts": "$module_attempts.module_attempts"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      created_at: { $first: "$created_at" },
      programs: { $push: "$programs.modules" },
      module_attempts: { $first: "$module_attempts" }
    }
  }
])
```

but results getting empty. Any idea how to get above results from this collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the model structure needs to modify as per best practice and it also will increase the query performance .

but it can done with `$replaceWith` and also the query will be quite long.

Noted: *`$replaceWith` support since `version 4.2`*

Solution: [MONGO_PLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y35PFjwAcKA)

code with explanation,

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: ObjectId("63ab0d0ed5e1b9566e0a2632"),
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$programs",
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$programs.modules",
  },

  // need to split the module_attempts an array 
  // so we can compare the Id value 

  {
    $project: {
      start_date: "$created_at",
      programs: "$programs.modules",
      tempModules: {
        $objectToArray: "$module_attempts",
      },
    },
  },

  // make the $tempModules to an Object
  {
    $unwind: "$tempModules",
  },
  
  // we use $cond (if-else-then) => required     

 {
    $project: {
      _id: "$_id",
      module_id: "$programs.module_id",
      module_instance_id: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$programs.module_id",
              "$tempModules.k"
            ],
            
          },
          then: "$programs.module_instance_id",
          else: null,
          
        },
        
      },
      tempModulesDeep: {
        $objectToArray: "$tempModules.v",
        
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  // in this stage, there will be an Object with module_instance_id: null
  {
    $match: {
      module_instance_id: {
        $ne: null,
        
      },
      
    }
  },
  //extrac tempModulesDeep
  {
    $unwind: "$tempModulesDeep",
    
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      _id: "$_id",
      start_date: "$tempModulesDeep.v.start_date",
      module_id: "$module_id",
      module_instance_id: "$module_instance_id"
    }
  }
```

[MONGO_PLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nFRw0G_8fGf)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. yes, its some old structure and not in good way.
but "start_date"  in result not the "created_at" date in top of the array.  it should be the "start_date"  in "module_attempts" .  that is the task actually I need to get.

Comment: yeah, you just need to change that. i made like that because i didnt find other date value.

Comment: the "start_date" in another array in $tempModules.k".  shall I call it as $tempModules.k.k" or need to $unwind ?  I've tried several ways but no luck.

Comment: @Miuranga you need to create array onbject again because it more deeper. i updated my answer and the mongo playground

Comment: we can also remove `$match` when checking nullable value, and useing `$ifNull` and `$ne`  inside `$cond`. just to make it more simply but it will be a bit hard to read.