# Using * in nested mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, atlas

I want to search  `{ "info.*.name":"a"}`

I have a document below :

```
id : "1" 
name : "abc"
 info : Object 
   123 : Object
       name : "a" 

id : "1" 
name : "abc"
 info : Object 
   1234 : Object
       name : "a"

id : "1" 
name : "abc"
 info : Object 
   12345: Object
       name : "a"
```

I want to search `{ "info.*.name":"a"}`

Comment: That's the bad when you have dynamic field names. You may consider to change your data design

Answer (score 0):

You have to put it manually, that would be:

```
db.document.find({
   info.key.name: "any"
})
```

and if the `key` is `dynamic`, you will need convert it to an array by using `aggregation` with `$objectToArray`

Example : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75597562/9267467

Comment: thanks alot , could you please help me writing that as compass query .

Comment: sure, please update your JSON data. just to make sure if i am not read it wrong. anyway. i also already put mongo playground link in the link. you may wanna try it first.